# question about polynomial multiplication

Tags: java, algorithm

i know that horners method for polynomial  pultiplication is faster but   here i dont know what is happening here is code

```
public class horner{

  public static  final  int n=10;
  public static  final  int x=7;

  public static void main(String[] args){
    //non fast version
    int a[]=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int xi=1;
    int y=a[0];
    for (int i=1;i<n;i++){
      xi=x*xi;
      y=y+a[i]*xi;
    }
    System.out.println(y);
    //fast method
    int y1=a[n-1];
    for (int  i=n-2;i>=0;i--){
      y1=x*y+a[i];
    }

    System.out.println(y1);
  }
}
```

result of this two methods are not same
result of first  method is

```
462945547
```

and result of second method is

```
-1054348465
```

please help

Comment: Hello, I have formatted and indented your code for you. Please take a moment to look at the revision that I made, so that you can see how to do the same in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `y` on the second loop:

```
y1=x*y+a[i];
```

This is where writing two function would come in handy - it would be impossible to reuse the same variable.

Comment: thanks sorry cool mistake thanks Kobi i did not pay attention

Answer (score 0):

Look at this loop:

```
for (int i=1;i<n;i++){ 
            xi=x*xi; 
            y=y+a[i]*xi; 
        }
```

I think you should use

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){ 
            xi=x*xi; 
            y=y+a[i]*xi; 
        }
```